# Shell.Run Ws.CurrentDirectory + "\somePath\chrome.exe --app=https://a.com" now work

Tags: vbscript

I want a vbs for opening Chrome and load a specific URL, but it doesn't work when the directory contains spaces.

My code, referred [shell.run with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223630/vbs-shell-run-with-variable/41225918#41225918), doesn't work. I'm just getting a error window saying

> System cannot find the specific file. Error code : 80070002

```vb
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
chromeLuncher = Ws.CurrentDirectory + "\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=https://www.google.com --start-maximized"
Ws.Run DblQuote(chromeLuncher), 1, True

'****************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'****************************************
```

How can I fix this?

**Update 1:**

The folder's structure:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         2018/6/4     10:42                Chrome
-a----         2018/6/4     15:23            190 fso.vbs
```

The Chrome's structure:

```
Chrome
 └─Application
    ├─61.0.3163.100
    │  ├─default_apps
    │  ├─Extensions
    │  ├─Installer
    │  ├─Locales
    │  ├─swiftshader
    │  ├─VisualElements
    │  └─WidevineCdm
    ├─Dictionaries
    ├─plugins
    ├─SetupMetrics
    └─chrome.exe
```

**Update 2:**

I tried the code [How to call Run() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025844/9144876), changed my code to:

```
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
chromeLuncher = """Ws.CurrentDirectory"" + ""\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=https://www.google.com --start-maximized"""
Ws.Run chromeLuncher,1,True
Ws = Nothing
```

but still got the same error:

[image: the error]

Comment: You need to add double quotes around the executable **path**, not the entire commandline.

Comment: I tried that way, not  work when the path is a variable, works fine when the path is a string.

Comment: No, you didn't. You tried to put a variable *inside* a string, which VBScript doesn't support. `DblQuote(Ws.CurrentDirectory & "/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe") & " --app=..."` Also, please don't edit answers into questions.

Comment: Aaaa, I misunderstood what you mean, it works. Sorry about the misunderstanding and I will remember `don't edit answers into questions`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim myURL 
Dim objShell
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

myURL = "https://www.google.com"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute Ws.CurrentDirectory+"\chrome.exe.lnk", myURL, "", "", 3
set objShell = nothing
```

You could have debugged your code, and you would have seen that the path you specify for chrome is wrong, that is why you receive the error on line 3.

Documentation for ShellExecute method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: you can place the shortcut to your chrome.exe install folder in the current folder for the vbs script.

Comment: The code works fine when chrome was installed with recommended steps. In my situation, cannot be sure there has one. So I put a installed Chrome floder in the vbs's path. Please see the update.

Comment: See the edited code.

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could  help!